# Delete Copies on Delete

Tags: java, alfresco

I am trying to set up a custom rule action for deleting copies of a node when it is deleted or moved.

Basically, we want to have a rule that when an item enters a folder, or is updated a copy is made to another folder. This works fine, but we also need it to do the reverse when the item is moved out of the folder or deleted.

Since a rule action doesn't exist to do that I am trying (poorly) to make my own that will accomplish the task, and it seems to function fine when the item is moved out of the folder, but fails if the item is deleted.

Here is my Executer below:

```
package ca.work.action.executer;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.ActionExecuterAbstractBase;
import org.alfresco.model.ContentModel;
import org.alfresco.query.PagingRequest;
import org.alfresco.query.PagingResults;
import org.alfresco.repo.action.ParameterDefinitionImpl;
import org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.MoveActionExecuter;
import org.alfresco.repo.transaction.AlfrescoTransactionSupport;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.action.Action;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.action.ParameterDefinition;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.coci.CheckOutCheckInService;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DataTypeDefinition;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.CopyService;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.CopyService.CopyInfo;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeService;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.rule.RuleServiceException;
import org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

/**
 * Delete Copy action executor.
 * <p>
 * Deletes any copies the actioned upon node has at a specified location.
 */
public class DeleteCopyActionExecuter extends ActionExecuterAbstractBase
{
    public static final String NAME = "delete copy";

    public static final String ERR_MULTIPLE = "Unable to delete copy because more than one have been found.";
    public static final String PARAM_DESTINATION_FOLDER = "destination-folder";

    private CopyService copyService;

    /**
     * The node service
     */
    private NodeService nodeService;
    private CheckOutCheckInService checkOutCheckInService;

    /**
     * Sets the node service
     */
    public void setNodeService(NodeService nodeService)
    {
        this.nodeService = nodeService;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the copy service
     */
    public void setCopyService(CopyService copyService)
    {
        this.copyService = copyService;
    }

    /**
     * Service to determine check-in or check-out status
     */
    public void setCheckOutCheckInService(CheckOutCheckInService checkOutCheckInService)
    {
        this.checkOutCheckInService = checkOutCheckInService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void addParameterDefinitions(List<ParameterDefinition> paramList)
    {
        paramList.add(new ParameterDefinitionImpl(
                PARAM_DESTINATION_FOLDER,
                DataTypeDefinition.NODE_REF,
                true,
                getParamDisplayLabel(PARAM_DESTINATION_FOLDER)
        ));
    }

    @Override
    public void executeImpl(Action ruleAction, NodeRef actionedUponNodeRef)
    {
        NodeRef destinationParent = (NodeRef) ruleAction.getParameterValue(PARAM_DESTINATION_FOLDER);

        // Since we are deleting we need to figure out whether the destination node exists
        NodeRef copyNodeRef = null;

        // Try and find copies of the actioned upon node reference.
        // Include the parent folder because that's where the copy will be if this action
        // had done the first copy.
        PagingResults<CopyInfo> copies = this.copyService.getCopies(
                actionedUponNodeRef,
                destinationParent,
                new PagingRequest(1000));

        for (CopyInfo copyInfo : copies.getPage()) {
            NodeRef copy = copyInfo.getNodeRef();
            // We know that it is in the destination parent, but avoid working copies
            if (this.checkOutCheckInService.isWorkingCopy(copy)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (copyNodeRef == null) {
                copyNodeRef = copy;
            } else {
                throw new RuleServiceException(ERR_MULTIPLE);
            }
        }

        if (copyNodeRef != null) {
            this.nodeService.deleteNode(copyNodeRef);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you not able to execute the rule, if node gets deleted ?
Which error are you getting  ?

Comment: There is no error. From a UI perspective it appears to complete successfully, but the copy isn't deleted.